# multiline with <ListItemText>

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

CODEPEN: https://codesandbox.io/s/94lw648lmo?fontsize=14

I have been using Material-ui with react.

I'm trying to make a list that contains long text.

When long text is given text is shown like the picture but, I want multiline text.

Here is my code snippet of it.

```
<List>
  {this.props.novels.map((novel, index) => (
  <ListItem alignItems="flex-start" key={index} role={undefined}>
    <ListItemText primary={<span>{novel.text}</span>} />
  <ListItemSecondaryAction>
    <Button>
      <ThumbUp />
    </Button>
    <span>{novel.like}</span>
    <Button>
      <ThumbDown />
    </Button>
    <span>{novel.dislike}</span>
  </ListItemSecondaryAction>
  </ListItem>
))}
</List>
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can add the following CSS to your cell:

```css
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answer did not work for me, here is what worked:

```
<ListItemText 
    primary={tooLongTitle} 
    primaryTypographyProps={{ style: { whiteSpace: "normal" } }} />
```

Comment: Thanks man this works fine for me, but in addition ensure that the option `disableTypography` is not being used in true.

Comment: is there any way to put line breaks in the ListItemText primary text in order to force multiple lines?

Comment: I can confirm that it's working in 5.x.

Comment: Setting ListItemText to width: "80%" or so will make the trick also. In case if text breaks too lately and still flows over the icons